# Converting first letter of a string to capital in xslt

Tags: html, xslt

I am new to XSLT and I need some help.
I have data stored in XML file and there is one attribute :

```
<clientName>JOHN GEORGE SMITH</clientName>
```

I am printing this name in my HTML file as follows:

```
<div>
    <xsl:value-of select="clientName"/>
</div>
```

I want my output to be : **John George Smith**.

I want the first letter to be capital for each word. I tried finding the solution online but couldn't find an appropriate way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I am not sure. I am using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem here is not how to capitalize each word, but how to tokenize the given text to individual words.

If it can be assumed that words are always separated by a space - or at least by a string that ends with a space - then you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="something">

    <!-- some stuff -->

    <div>
        <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="clientName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </div>

    <!-- other stuff -->

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="capitalize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>

    <xsl:variable name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="word" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 1, 1), $lower-case, $upper-case)"/>    
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 2), $upper-case, $lower-case)"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that this will fail with values such as:

```
<clientName>HILLARY RODHAM-CLINTON</clientName>
<clientName>HILLARY (RODHAM) CLINTON</clientName>
<clientName>GEORGE BUSH THE THIRD</clientName>
<clientName>CHARLES DE GAULLE</clientName>
<clientName>RENÉE ZELLWEGER</clientName>
```

and probably others I cannot think of at the moment.

Comment: This worked and the way you wrote the code is self-explanatory. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It didn't fail in 3rd, 4th and 5th case. Why did you think that it would fail?

Comment: 3) "The" instead of "the"; 4) "De" instead of "de"; 5) "RenÉe" instead of "Renée" (I changed this to a better example).

Comment: I checked again and it's failing in first two cases only.

Comment: Do you not get "Charles De Gaulle" as the result in the 4th case? The correct result is "Charles de Gaulle". This is a difficult problem that has nothing to do with XSLT. In some cases, it's impossible to restore the original spelling: if your input is "MACKENZIE", you have no way of telling if their real name is "MacKenzie" or "Mackenzie".

Comment: I did get "Charles De Gaulle" in the 4th case but I didn't realize that and it will be difficult to cover all the cases and I think your solution works in most of the cases which is fine for me at the moment.