# Converting first string letter to capital and rest of the letters in lower case, with two delimiters

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I started learning XSLT, kind of got stuck while writing xslt functions for converting from lower-case to upper-case and upper-case to lower-case in xslt

I have tried a lot by writing different xslt functions but I think some where I'm doing mistake in my code

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertXmlStyleToCamelCase">

    <xsl:param name="occupation"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select='/'/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter2" select= "' '"/>

    <xsl:if test="not($occupation = '')" >
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($occupation, $delimiter)">
                <xsl:variable name="word" select="substring-before(concat($occupation, $delimiter), $delimiter)"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$word">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 1, 1), $lowercase, $uppercase)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word,2), $uppercase, $lowercase)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>


            <xsl:when test="contains( $occupation, $delimiter)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <!-- Recursive call to template to translate the text after delimeter -->
                <xsl:call-template name="ConvertXmlStyleToCamelCase">
                        <xsl:with-param name="occupation"  select="substring-after($occupation, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="contains($occupation, $delimiter2)">
                <xsl:variable name="word2" select="substring-before(concat($occupation, $delimiter2), $delimiter2)"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$word2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word2, 1, 1), $lowercase, $uppercase)"></xsl:value-of>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word2, 2), $uppercase, $lowercase)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="contains($occupation, $delimiter2)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter2"/>
                <!-- Recursive call to template to translate the text after delimeter2 -->
                <xsl:call-template name="ConvertXmlStyleToCamelCase">
                    <xsl:with-param name="occupation"  select="substring-after($occupation, $delimiter2)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="not($occupation = $delimiter and $delimiter2)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(occupation, 1, 1)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(occupation, 2), $uppercase, $lowercase)"/>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

input will be any one value from the below

1.SELF/EMPLOYED
2.SKILL TRADE
3.GOVERNMENT

Expected output as below

1. Self/Employed
2. Skill Trade
3. Government

But the actual outcome is

1. SelfSelf employed
2. Skill/trade
3. Government

Comment: A template cannot contain another template - so the result you report cannot be.

Comment: Are you sure you're constrained to XSLT version 1.0? It's very limiting for operations like this.

Comment: @Kay its legacy systems right now the requirements are on this

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, your code is not reproducible. From the results you report it is clear that your 2nd delimiter is not applied. AFAICT, it is because you check first for the existence of the 1st delimiter - and if you find it, you do not bother to test if the 2nd delimiter exists **before** the 1st one.

Consider the following example (adapted from [Converting first letter of a string to capital in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186517/converting-first-letter-of-a-string-to-capital-in-xslt)):

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>Self/Employed</item>
    <item>Skill Trade</item>
    <item>Government</item>
    <item>a combi/na/tion of various de/limi/ters</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <caps>
                <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </caps>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="capitalize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>

    <xsl:variable name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="word" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$delimiter=' '">
            <!-- tokenize word by 2nd delimiter -->
            <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$word"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'/'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- capitalize word -->
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 1, 1), $lower-case, $upper-case)"/>    
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 2), $upper-case, $lower-case)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <caps>Self/Employed</caps>
  <caps>Skill Trade</caps>
  <caps>Government</caps>
  <caps>A Combi/Na/Tion Of Various De/Limi/Ters</caps>
</output>
```

Comment: first Thank you so much for quick response Really appreciated!!! you are right sir there shouldn't be two templates I was just blindly reading from stack overflow functions and testing in my local :) 
1question: From the xml there would be only one value as input it could be any one of them from above three formats as I mentioned so I commented match template calling capitalize template directly like below

Comment: <req:occupation>
                            <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
                                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="occupation"></xsl:with-param>
2. curious to know why you have written        <xsl:template match="/input">
3. what happens if the value comes as empty any runtime error throws by xslt since we are not keeping any conditions to check null or empty ' '

Comment: @nick I think you can answer these questions yourself.

Comment: trying to understand your code can you pls help me here,  you declared in template     <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/> if I give input $text = SKILLED TRADE then word = SKILLED and next it pass the <xsl:when test="$delimiter=' '"> and it calls template and delimeter value changes to '/'  and now in choose block when condition fails it capitilize the word to Skilled and now <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)"> the given text is SKILLED TRADE it will not pass this condition right since delimeter value overrided to '/'

Comment: It's almost correct. Te **first** word is SKILLED and that's the new $text that's passed to the template, along with `/` as the parameter. And since this text does not contain the parameter, the processing ends there. The second word is passed back using the recursive call at the end. HTH.

Comment: Once we pass the $text  = SKILLED  and parameter / to template it concats values becomes SKILLED/ and then word = SKILLED and comes to <xsl:when test="$delimiter=' '"> it fails here since the delimeter value is / and it falls otherwise block capitalize to Skilled and but to do same fashion for second word it should pass <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
 Condition right ? but the values will (Skilled TRADE, /)how it pass here little confuse am I missing something please correct me. In (Skilled/TRADE) scenario it pass since the original text we are passing having with /

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. What do you use as your testing environment? In cases like this, it is best to insert `xsl:message`  at key points to follow the processing chain.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have more than two delimiters in the future? If so, try this XSLT, which can be readily extended to have more (single character) delimiters. Just change the `delimiters` parameters in the `ConvertXmlStyleToCamelCase` template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <item>
            <xsl:call-template name="ConvertXmlStyleToCamelCase" />
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ConvertXmlStyleToCamelCase">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiters" select="' /'"/>

        <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nextDelimiter" select="substring(translate($text, translate($text, $delimiters, ''), ''), 1, 1)" />
        <xsl:variable name="string" select="substring-before(concat($text, ' '), substring(concat($nextDelimiter, ' '), 1, 1))" />

        <xsl:message terminate="no">Next delimiter is <xsl:value-of select="$nextDelimiter" /></xsl:message>

        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($string, 1, 1), $lower, $upper)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($string, 2), $upper, $lower)"/>

        <xsl:if test="$nextDelimiter">
            <xsl:value-of select="$nextDelimiter" />
            <xsl:call-template name="ConvertXmlStyleToCamelCase">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $nextDelimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="$delimiters"/>  
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeR where I have used a third delimiters as an example.

With reference to the double-translate, the purpose of this is to find the next delimiter in the string. To do this (in XSLT 1.0) you need to remove all the characters that are not delimiters. Doing `translate($text, $delimiters, '')` removes all delimiters, and so returns all characters that are not delimiters. If you then apply this result to the original string, you are left with just the delimiters present. The first character will then be the next delimiter.

Comment: Thankyou for the response to make it clear for example if I pass input as SKILLED/LABOR the value of nextdelimeter =  ' ' if it is right then we can do simply string = "substring-before($text, nextdelimeter)"  then string = SKILLED it modifies to Skilled. similar fashion it will do for other word.

Comment: Ignore my first comment Since I’m new to XSLT trying to understand if I give input as SKILLED/LABOR 1. translate($text, $delimiters, '') = SKILLEDLABOR 2. translate($text, translate($text, $delimiters, ''), '') = (SKILLED/LABOR, SKILLEDLABOR, ‘’)  what ouput we get here ? is / or SKILLEDLABOR could you please give me detail explanation also can you please insert xsl:message to output the value of nextdelimeter and string I want print the values in logs I’m not sure about the syntax

Comment: I've extended my answer to explain the double-translate, and added an `xsl:message`, although you can find the syntax at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_message.asp

Comment: Thankyou!! it make sense to me now nextdelimeter will be = / or '  ' but the xsl:message is not printing value in my logs not sure do I need to enable logs somewhere else well its an enterprise application

Comment: If you are having an issue with `xsl:message` then should probably ask a whole new question, giving as much information about your application as possible. Thanks.